# Generate array of textbox in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the below ruby code

```
<%= form_for :post, url:"/index" do |f|%>
    <%= f.text_field(:name) %>
<% end %>
```

This generates a form with textbox as below

```
<input type="text" name="post[name]" id="post_name">
```

Is there any way to generate fields with array format such as:

```
<input type="text" name="post[name][]" id="post_name_1">
<input type="text" name="post[name][]" id="post_name_2">
<input type="text" name="post[name][]" id="post_name_3">
<input type="text" name="post[name][]" id="post_name_4">
:
:
<input type="text" name="post[name][]" id="post_name_n">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the name like this

```
<%= f.text_field(:field_name, :name => "post[name][]") %>
```

and then do it like this:

```
<%(1..n).each do |i|%>
<%= f.text_field(:name, :name => "post[name][]", :id => "post_name_#{i}") %>
<%end%>
```